# Can we make correlated queries with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate this SQL query into a Flask-SQLAlchemy call:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "ENVOI"
WHERE "ID_ENVOI" IN (SELECT d."ID_ENVOI"
                     FROM "DECLANCHEMENT" d
                     WHERE d."STATUS" = 0
                                    AND d."DATE" = (SELECT max("DECLANCHEMENT"."DATE")
                                    FROM "DECLANCHEMENT"
                                    WHERE "DECLANCHEMENT"."ID_ENVOI" = d."ID_ENVOI"))
```

As you can see, it uses subqueries and, most important part, one of the subqueries is a correlated query (it use `d` table defined in an outer query).

I know how to use subqueries with `subquery()` function, but I can't find documentation about correlated queries with SQLAlchemy. Do you know a way to do it ?

Comment: "correlated subquery" is a much more common term than "synchronized subquery". You can find examples in the [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link from univerio's comment, I've done this code for my request:

```py
Declch = db.aliased(Declanchement)

maxdate_sub = db.select([db.func.max(Declanchement.date)])\
                .where(Declanchement.id_envoi == Declch.id_envoi)

decs_sub = db.session.query(Declch.id_envoi)\
            .filter(Declch.status == SMS_EN_ATTENTE)\
            .filter(Declch.date < since)\
            .filter(Declch.date == maxdate_sub).subquery()

envs = Envoi.query.filter(Envoi.id_envoi.in_(decs_sub)).all()
```

Comment: how would I use maxdate_sub in main query if the subquery returns multiple rows?

Comment: It's been years, I don't play with it these days, but I guess you would use functions like `in_` (see `decs_sub` in this case)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we can.

Have a look at the following example (especially the `correlate` method call):

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func, table, Column, Integer

table1 = table('table1', Column('col', Integer))
table2 = table('table2', Column('col', Integer))


subquery = select(
    [func.if_(table1.c.col == 1, table2.c.col, None)]
).correlate(table1)

query = (
    select([table1.c.col,
            subquery.label('subquery')])
    .select_from(table1)
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(query)
```

will result in the following query

```
SELECT table1.col, (SELECT if(table1.col = :col_1, table2.col, NULL) AS if_1 
FROM table2) AS subquery 
FROM table1
```

As you can see, if you call `correlate` on a `select`, the given `Table` will not be added to it's `FROM`-clause.
You have to do this even when you specify `select_from` directly, as SQLAlchemy will happily add any table it finds in the columns.